# SP_RENAME causing 'invalid column name' issue

Tags: database, ssms, sql-server-2014, sp-rename

I say 'issue' because it's not breaking anything, it's merely a small thing I've noticed in SSMS.

I run the following:

`SP_RENAME 'MyTable.OldName', 'NewName' , 'COLUMN'`

And then type the following in SSMS:

`SELECT [NewName] FROM MyTable;`

The `[NewName]` part now has a red squiggly line under it with a 'Invalid column name' warning.

Why? Is the old name cached in SSMS somehow somewhere? Is my column rename incomplete somehow? I don't really care if it's a bug of SSMS, but I'd like to know there isn't a 'step 2' I'm meant to do once renaming a column.

Note: If I type `SELECT [OldName] FROM MyTable;` I don't get the warning, but it (obviously) doesn't run.

Comment: *"Is the old name cached in SSMS somehow somewhere"* - Yes; Go to Edit => IntelliSense => Refresh or Ctrl+Shift+R to make it update itself. You don't need to do anything else, its a false warning.

Comment: Sorted! Thanks. Post it as the answer so I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Is the old name cached in SSMS somehow somewhere"* - Yes.

Go to *Edit* => *IntelliSense* => *Refresh* or *Ctrl*+*Shift*+*R* to make it update itself.

You don't need to do anything else, its a false warning.

Comment: I suppose this does not work in a single transaction, as SSMS doesn't know the column was renamed by `sp_rename` just before.